# oscommerce and wordpress integrates with joomla

Tags: wordpress, joomla, oscommerce

Is there any way to combine oscommerce with wordpress.Basically i need to combine joomla, oscommerce and wordpress into a single domain and use a unique template for all.also i want to introduce single sign on for all the applications.is it possible?  please help.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [wordpress for joomla](http://www.corephp.com/joomla-products/wordpress-for-joomla.html) which integrates wordpress into joomla and installs as a component into joomla. Description from their site:

> We’ve combined the most popular blogging platform (WordPress) with the
>   most popular CMS (Joomla!) to create the most powerful blogging
>   component ever made for Joomla!.
>
> Introducing WordPress for Joomla!: an exciting new component for
>   Joomla! that integrates WordPress into your blog!
>
> Packed with all of WordPress’s professional blogging tools (plus a few
>   surprises of our own!), you can now harness the power of WordPress
>   without ever leaving Joomla!. It’s a Joomla! blogger’s new best
>   friend.

For oscommerce integration there is this The josC! Project: osCommerce and Joomla Bridge project.Get a copy from [here](http://addons.oscommerce.com/info/7235) There are plenty enough powerful shop builders for joomla and you may search for them on [JED](http://extensions.joomla.org)

Answer (score 0):

Wel you can try marvikshop. That's a oscommerce component for joomla. You can download it [here](http://marvikshop.com)

Comment: That's not what the OP was asking.